# Pie Chart using Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, python-3.6

I'm using Jupyter notebook that is drawing a bar chart in offline mode without issues.

I have a Pandas dataframe from reading in a CSV file and I want to quickly create a pie chart in Plotly (offline mode).

Plotly pie chart values (https://plot.ly/python/reference/#pie-values) counts the labels if omitted. That's what I had hoped for. I wanted to set the pie chart labels (https://plot.ly/python/reference/#pie-labels) directly from my pandas dataframe.

My code:

```
import plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode

init_notebook_mode()

df2 = pd.read_csv("./testdata.csv")

trace = go.Pie(
    labels= df2["Vendor"]
)

py.offline.plot(trace, filename='pdq_pie_chart.html')
```

I get an error when attempting this:

```
PlotlyError: The `figure_or_data` positional argument must be `dict`-like, `list`-like, or an instance of plotly.graph_objs.Figure
```

Did I miss something in the lead up to the go.Pie call? I deliberately didn't get into any formatting options, and wanted to generate the pie chart with as little code as possible from the dataframe.

Comment: Can you share test data and did you try `labels= df2["Vendor"].values` ?

Comment: hey @W.Dodge... I just tried that and no luck. I also just substituted simple arrays for labels and values, and still get the same error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you required labels and values parameter to draw a pie chart in plotly.
This example will use to draw a pie chart.

```
labels = df2['Vendor'].value_counts().index
values = df2['Vendor'].value_counts().values

trace = go.Pie(labels=labels, values=values)

py.iplot([trace], filename='basic_pie_chart')
```